# Linear interpolation over a list of data frames

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to perform a linear interpolation of mean water level for each data frame contained in a list of data frames (1038 in total) using the apply family of functions, but I am having trouble defining the variables in the interpolation function to point to columns within each data frame.

Here is the head of my list:

```
head(df_list)
$`1928-01-01`
      station date_measured daily_mean max min mean      lon      lat
8267 20250000    1928-01-01          0 453 193  272 -49.5519 -15.2753
8268 20250000    1928-01-01          0 453 191  276 -49.5519 -15.2753

$`1928-02-01`
      station date_measured daily_mean max min mean      lon      lat
8269 20250000    1928-02-01          0  NA  NA   NA -49.5519 -15.2753
8270 20250000    1928-02-01          0  NA  NA   NA -49.5519 -15.2753

$`1928-03-01`
      station date_measured daily_mean max min mean      lon      lat
8271 20250000    1928-03-01          0 394 219  282 -49.5519 -15.2753
8272 20250000    1928-03-01          0 382 218  281 -49.5519 -15.2753

$`1928-04-01`
      station date_measured daily_mean max min mean      lon      lat
8273 20250000    1928-04-01          0 280 176  224 -49.5519 -15.2753
8274 20250000    1928-04-01          0 287 178  223 -49.5519 -15.2753

$`1928-05-01`
      station date_measured daily_mean max min mean      lon      lat
8275 20250000    1928-05-01          0 199 161  172 -49.5519 -15.2753
8276 20250000    1928-05-01          0 197 162  173 -49.5519 -15.2753

$`1928-06-01`
      station date_measured daily_mean max min mean      lon      lat
8277 20250000    1928-06-01          0 174 132  149 -49.5519 -15.2753
8278 20250000    1928-06-01          0 173 132  149 -49.5519 -15.2753
```

This is what I tried originally:

```
daily_int <- lapply(df_list, function(x) interp(x=lon,y=lat,z=mean, method="linear"))
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
 Error in interp(x = lon, y = lat, z = mean, method = "linear") : 
  object 'lat' not found
```

I realize the interp function is not finding the column that I want it to look at, and being new to the apply family, I'm not sure how to do that (or if it's even possible). Essentially, I need to interpolate daily water levels across a river, and I'd like to do it in the most efficient way possible while keeping the days separate.

Edit based on comment: I'm trying to predict the mean, min, and max for each data frame.

Comment: What package are using to call your function `interp`?  It is not in `base`.

Comment: It's the interp package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not exactly sure which values you are trying to predict for using the interp function

As far as the lapply goes: each value in the list becomes the *x* in the function. 
So using `with()` you can assign the data frame you are working with in the interp function.

```
daily_int <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
    out <- with(x,interp(x=lon,y=lat,z=mean, method="linear"))
    return(out)
})
```

i dont have R open to test this and am not familiar with interp off the top of my head, so will update later!

Comment: In theory, this is working, but I'm having other problems with the data based on the interpolation. Working to get the data corrected so I can make sure it's working properly.

Comment: I think the key take home for your question is that you needed to make sure the `x` in `function(x)` is representing the data frame. Then you can either use the `with` function, or you can use `$` as in `x=x$lon,y=x$lat`. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with the `interp` function you are using but in general if you want to access the column names of the data frames in an `lapply` loop the following should work:

```
daily_int <- lapply(df_list, function(x) interp(x=x$lon,y=x$lat,z=x$mean, method="linear"))
```

Does that work? If not maybe this will work:

```
daily_int <- lapply(df_list, function(x) interp(x=x[["lon"]],y=x[["lat"]],z=x[["mean"]], method="linear"))
```